# Common y label on matplotlib not adjusting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have two subplots and would like to have common x- and y-axes labels for both. My code is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

ax.set_ylabel("array2 stuff")

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(array1, array2, 'o-', label='stuff')
plt.title("my stuff")

plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(array1, array2, 'o-', label='stuff')
plt.xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("array2 stuff")
plt.legent(loc="lower left")
plt.ylim(-constant, constant)
plt.grid()

plot.show()
```

The x-axis label appears to work, but the y-label just won't center between the two plots. Instead it centers on the lower plot's y-axis.

Answer (score 5):

Use `text`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array1 = np.linspace(-10,10,10)
array2 = np.linspace(-10,10,10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(array1, array2, 'o-', label='stuff')
plt.title("my stuff")

plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(array1, array2, 'o-', label='stuff')
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
constant = 10
plt.ylim(-constant, constant)
plt.grid()
fig.text(.05, .5, 'array stuff', ha='center', va='center', rotation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for that. Although what I'm looking for is only one ylabel, that is common to both plots and centred. Looking at my code, any ideas where I've gone wrong? The "ax.set_ylabel("array2 stuff")" didn't work (not the "ax", and not "ax1" or "ax2".

Comment: Ok, I add a text object for common label. Look above.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!